# Output Issue in Connect Four Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i execute this code in my browser, i get accurate result for connecting the circles in all the directions except when i start to connect the diagonals from the first column and the second column i.e. from the left of your screen start creating the diagonal from the first circle from the bottom of the first column and first circle from the bottom of the second column. The output of my heading1 changes in all the other cases but not in this case. Please help me out fixing the error. Try to run the code snippet to understand my problem. Thanks!!!

```js
var player1 = prompt("Player 1 Enter Your Name, You Are Orange");
var player1Color = 'rgb(255, 165, 0)';
var player2 = prompt("Player 2 Enter Your Name, You Are Green");
var player2Color = 'rgb(34, 139, 34)';

var table = $('table tr');

function changeColor(rowIndex, colIndex, color){
  return table.eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).find('button').css('background-color', color);
}

function returnColor(rowIndex, colIndex){
  return table.eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).find('button').css('background-color');
}

function checkBottom(col){
  for(var row = 5; row > -1; row--){
    var reportColor = returnColor(row, col);
    if(reportColor === 'rgb(128, 128, 128)'){
      return row;
    }
  }
}

function checkColorMatch(one, two, three, four){
  return one === two && one === three && one === four && one !== 'rgb(128, 128, 128)' && one !== undefined;
}

function horizontalWinCheck(){
  for(var row = 0; row < 6; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col < 4; col++){
      if(checkColorMatch(returnColor(row, col), returnColor(row, col + 1), returnColor(row, col + 2), returnColor(row, col + 3))){
        return true;
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

function verticalWinCheck(){
  for(var col = 0; col < 7; col++){
    for(var row = 0; row < 3; row++){
      if(checkColorMatch(returnColor(row, col), returnColor(row + 1, col), returnColor(row + 2, col), returnColor(row + 3, col))){
        return true;
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

function diagonalWinCheck(){
  for(var col = 0; col < 5; col++){
    for(var row = 0; row < 7; row++){
      if (checkColorMatch(returnColor(row, col), returnColor(row + 1, col + 1), returnColor(row + 2, col + 2), returnColor(row + 3, col + 3))) {
        console.log("Diag");
        return true;
      }else if(checkColorMatch(returnColor(row, col), returnColor(row - 1, col + 1), returnColor(row - 2, col + 2), returnColor(row - 3, row + 3))){
        console.log("Diag");
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

var currentPlayer = 1;
var currentName = player1;
var currentColor = player1Color;

$('h3').text(currentName + " It's Your Turn Start The Game");

$('.board button').on('click', function(){
  var col = $(this).closest('td').index();
  var availBottom = checkBottom(col);
  changeColor(availBottom, col, currentColor);
  if (horizontalWinCheck() || verticalWinCheck() || diagonalWinCheck()){
    $('h1').text(currentName + " You Won The Game!!!");
  }
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer * -1;
  if (currentPlayer === 1) {
    currentName = player1;
    $('h3').text(currentName + " It's Your Turn");
    currentColor = player1Color;
  }else{
    currentName = player2;
    $('h3').text(currentName + " It's Your Turn");
    currentColor = player2Color;
  }
})
```

```css
.board button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connect Four</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center">
      <h1>Welcome To Connect Four</h1>
      <h2>Connect Four Cirles to Win The Game</h2>
      <h3>Let's Start!!!</h3>
      <table class="board">
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
          <td><button></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Row index starts from 0 at the **top** of the grid, so dots are built starting from row 5.
In function diagonalWinCheck, the inner loop should be `for(var row = 8; row--;){`.
Also in the else if you have a `returnColor(row - 3, row + 3)` instead of a `returnColor(row - 3, col + 3)`.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer....but did you check by making the changes in the code??

Comment: I spotted the error by debugging in Firefox using a breakpoint in your code and using the inspector. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I upvoted the question and answer both. Neeraj, welcome to stack overflow. Please mark this answer as `accept as answer`.